# Kafka TimeoutException stops Application Startup - How do I properly handle this case?

Tags: java, spring-boot, error-handling, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We are using Kafka Consumers in our Spring Boot application. When creating the beans the KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry is created and try to fetch the data for the Containers. The problem is now, that we sometimes receive a TimeoutException which stops the application start up. See full stacktrace.

```
2019-08-28 07:49:46,053 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:893)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
    at com.pack.MyApplication.createRootApplicationContext(MyApplication.java:45)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5132)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1849)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata
```

Since I'm new to Kafka I'm not sure how to handle this correctly, so that my application will start also if the meta data cannot be fetched.

I thought about setting the ErrorHandler for the ContainerFactory but I'm not sure if this will resolve my issue.

```
    @Bean
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>
    kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setRetryTemplate(getRetryTemplate());
        factory.setErrorHandler(new LoggingErrorHandler());
        factory.setAutoStartup(false);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RetryPolicy getRetryPolicy(){
        SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        simpleRetryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(getMaxRetryAttempts());
        return simpleRetryPolicy;
    }

    @Bean
    public FixedBackOffPolicy getBackOffPolicy() {
        FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(getRetryInterval());
        return backOffPolicy;
    }

    @Bean
    public RetryTemplate getRetryTemplate(){
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(getRetryPolicy());
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(getBackOffPolicy());
        return retryTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {

        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, env.getProperty("spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers"));
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, env.getProperty("spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer"));
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, env.getProperty("spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer"));
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, env.getProperty("spring.kafka.consumer.group-id"));
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, env.getProperty("spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset"));
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, env.getProperty("spring.kafka.consumer.client-id"));

        props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, env.getProperty("kafka.sasl.mechanism"));
        props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, env.getProperty("kafka.security.protocol.config"));
        props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, env.getProperty("kafka.sasl.jaas.configuration"));

        try {
            Resource res = new ClassPathResource(env.getProperty("spring.kafka.ssl.trust-store-location"));
            props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, res.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("SSL Truststore for Kafka connection could not be found!", e);
        }
        props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, env.getProperty("avro.kafka.consumer.deserializer.schema-url"));
        props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG,
                env.getProperty("avro.kafka.consumer.deserializer.specific-avro-reader"));

        return props;
    }

    private int getMaxRetryAttempts(){
        return this.retryAttempts;
    }

    private int getRetryInterval(){
        return this.retryInterval;
    }
```

Anyone can explain how the ContainerStoppingErrorHandler works in this case and if it might resolve my issue?
I also thought about creating the KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry bean myself, but don't know how to configure so the Exception is handled properly and the application start up will continue. Maybe the autoStartup is something I should consider in this case and if so, whats might be the correct way to control and handle the start up for the containers?

The Versions used: 
spring-kafka version 2.2.7.RELEASE
spring-boot-starter-parent 2.1.6.RELEASE

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When asking questions like this; always provide the version you are using; also edit the question to show the full stack trace; we can't help without knowing exactly where the problem occurred. An error handler on the container factory won't help. 

Just to be clear; the framework does not normally do anything that causes a fetch of metadata on the `main` thread, so it appears to be something in your configuration. Hence the need for a stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I added the full stack trace and also added the config.

Comment: Could you share the value of         ```env.getProperty("kafka.security.protocol.config" ``` ?  This can happen when broker wait for SSL connection and the client is not using SSL

Comment: That's not the full stack trace; it is truncated at the `Caused by:` - we need to see it all.